# Sitecore 9.1 Content tree gets wiped out

Tags: sql-database, content-tree

I am facing a weird issue in my local instance the content tree home node subitems are getting deleted in a random frequency. I am restoring the master database every time this happens.

I am running in **live mode** with web connection string pointing to master db. I have never published anything since its running in live mode. I have checked the logs and history table to see what might cause this issue but no luck.

I am using **TDS** with manual sync but the content node is not part of the VS solution. The following packages are installed **Sitecore Sidekick**, **Sitecron**(all jobs stopped), **Coveo** and **Brightcove**.

Recently I tried some sql query monitoring the items table on deletion would log to another table which didnt record anything either.

Comment: I am not so much sure, but can you please check if you have some custom event that is responsible for this.

Comment: It either sync or publish. Check event queue or history tables for anything suspicious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally we were able get to the bottom of the issue. It was related to the Brightcove content import job that was wiping the content tree only on the local dev instances due to import failure.